# Bash programming looping in if and case statement

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, case

Why is it the code on "if" statement will keep looping if null is input to "title" variable but for the case statement, my script will have error?

```
 echo -n "Title :"
      read title   
   if [ -z "$title" ]; then
 echo "Please input a title"  
   while [[ -z "$title" ]] ; do
 echo -n "Title: "
      read title
   done
   fi



read author
     case "$author" in
     *[0-9,\""\!@#$%\(\)]*) echo "Please enter a name" ;;
      while  *[1-9,\""\!@#$%\(\)]*)"$author" ]] ; do
     echo -n "author "
          read author
      esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 while  *[1-9,\""\!@#$%\(\)]*)"$author" ]] ; do
```

wouldn't be allowed there even if there weren't a bunch a syntax errors in it. Try this idiom instead:

```
title=
while [ -z "$title ] 
do
    read -p "What is the title? " title
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You have \""  and should be only \" . That's the syntax error

Also, you can't put a While as a case. Try this and add any cases you want

```
while [ -z $author ]; do
echo "Please enter an author: "
read author  
case "$author" in
    *[0-9,\"\!@#$%\(\)]*) echo "First case - $author"
    ;;
esac
done
```